# TFS Stops working

Tags: tfs

We face daily issue related to TFS. TFS stops working all of a sudden and it just keeps loading (No error message) and It works well after we reset the IIS. I've checked the Event Logs but no idea how to resolve the Issue.

If anyone can suggest something it would be of great help.

Comment: Did you check also the Microsoft-Team Foundation Server/Debug logs in Event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

If you can rest IIS to fix this issue. It may related to Microsoft-Team Foundation Server Application Pool. You can find it in **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**→**Application Pools**→**Microsoft-Team Foundation Server Application Pool**

Check the **Application Logs** and **System Logs** in Event Viewer→WindowsLogs, whether there are some related information. And also check **C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr#.log** which related to IIS.

If its cause by Microsoft-Team Foundation Server Application Pool, there is a walkaroud for your situation : right click this pool **select recycling settings**, check specific time(s), specify a value like 23:00. It will daily recycle when 23:00.